# Rest Api Patterns Explanation?

Tags: php, rest, yii

I am new to making rest api.

i want to know how routing of rest api works. i have a api which works in one routing and doesn't in another.. what exact modifications do i need to make in order to bind each api call to specific VERB.

for example i want /customer/view to only be called by GET verb, put and post should not be able to make this call, is this possible to do with routes settings

here are my routes..

one which works is here below :

```
'<controller:\w+>'                   => '<controller>/list',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'      => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'  => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'          => '<controller>/view',
```

One which doesnt work is this..specially view which is called like this, basically i am able to call it from any VERB, how to bind to specific verb

```
https://myipaddress/wiz-frontend-himanshu/customer/view/?id=test
```

rest routes

```
array('customer/list', 'pattern'=>'customer/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('customer/view', 'pattern'=>'customer/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('customer/update', 'pattern'=>'customer/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
array('customer/delete', 'pattern'=>'customer/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
array('customer/create', 'pattern'=>'customer/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
```

Can anyone explain, what this pattern exactly does, and what changes do i need to make, to run my view call

Comment: What you expect from us is not really clear. I encourage you to edit your question to fix it.

Comment: @FlorianF. i am admitting embarrassingly, that i dont know how URI is mapped using this pattern, and how it can be bind to a specific verb. for example, i want /api/view to be only called by GET verb, if someone uses any other verb, it should not be allowed

Comment: According to the code you posted and [this documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls) your routes should work as intended. Maybe you could update your question including those precisions. +1

Comment: yeah, thats the exact documentation i am following, but ... nevertheless its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood, but i guess you need to do the following:

Put your api controllers in separate module (named for example `api`) and specify follow rules in your url manager:

```
// GET
array('api/<controller>/list', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('api/<controller>/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
// POST
array('api/<controller>/create', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
// PUT
array('api/<controller>/update', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
array('api/<controller>/update', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
// DELETE
array('api/<controller>/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
array('api/<controller>/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
```

So you can call your api by this url's:

> GET: /api/users - list of users (`actionList()` in `users` controller)
>
> GET: /api/users/12  - user with id = 12 (`actionView()` in `users`
>   controller)
>
> POST: /api/user - create new user (`actionCreate()` in `users` controller)
>
> PUT: /api/user/12 - update user with id = 12 (`actionUpdate()` in `users`
>   controller)
>
> DELETE: /api/user/12 - delete user with id = 12 (`actionDelete()` in `users`
>   controller)

Comment: @Himanshu97 You can try to use this extension:
https://github.com/goodnickoff/yiirestmodel

Comment: I have just edited post. There were some errors in url's examples.